# Fabric capacity not being used completely

Tags: azure-synapse-analytics, microsoft-fabric

Iam using azure fabric capacity F4 for running my spark application. This spark application written in pyspark reads messages (URLS of news articles) from eventhub with 8 partitions and process it using external API and then writes it to the target eventhub. For processing 10 messages it takes anything between 8 to 25 seconds which is very slow for spark application which is suppose to process parallely.

I have used microsoft fabric capacity metric app to understand utilization of fabric resource for running my job. I have found that it is not using all resources

[8 tasks running on 1 executor as 8 partitions being used while reading data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbxRB.png)

[Usage Fabric capacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hKft.png)

[Tasks getting queued as only one executor being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih0d0.png)

I want to understand how i can use full capacity of fabric.  Is there any configuration that i need change or set. Do i need to make dynamic allocation on, how to do it ?

I can also provide piece of code and details on source eventhub.

Look forward for any help, thank you.

I tried setting spark configuration i am setting through code is as provided below

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \

    .appName("EventHub Processing Article") \

    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.1,com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.18") \

    .config("spark.executor.cores", "4") \

    .config("spark.executor.instances", "2") \

    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true") \

    .getOrCreate()
```

I was expecting second executor also getting active and process all 8 tasks parallel.